# Sdk is missing the Android Support Repository

Tags: javafx, gluon-mobile

I'm trying to make a app with Gluon mobile but i'm not able to make the Android version work. 
I try to download the SDK directly from android but the SDKManager will not open.

After some research I find that SDKManager is not support anymore.

I install Android studio, but the Support Repository is now obsolete.

Anybody know how I can make it work?

I change my JavaJDK to 1.8 instead of java 11 or 12 but still nothing.

Thanks
Jc

Comment: See this [guide](https://docs.gluonhq.com/getting-started/#android-support) to install the required Android tools.

Answer (score 0):

The Gluon Plug-in won't deploy to Android with gradle task `androidInstall` as the Android SDK is missing "Android Support Repository" which is no longer available with current versions of Android Studio, but the `androidInstall` gradle task console-log outputs a DOS command-line showing how to download it.
Something like:
`C:/Users/.../Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "extras;android;m2repository"`
(the above is described in the link mentioned earlier by José Pereda)